# How to make a multiplayer game for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: camera, python, maps, mobile, projection

I am making a 2d multiplayer game for Android, targeted to run on every device.

How do I calculate the common position of an asset, independent of screen size?

What size map should I assume is a global size for every device?

If I make it with respect to the map does it affect the game map display on a mobile screen?

My game design and game will be similar to Brawl Star:
[image: Example: Brawl Star]

Comment: Think of every 2D multiplayer game you've ever played, and all the ones you've seen or heard about but haven't played. Do they all use *exactly* the same on-screen presentation? If not, then you probably need to give us more details about how *your specific* game is supposed to look on each screen. Otherwise, we can't guess which of these different styles of game you plan to make, and we might give you advice for a different kind of game than what you're making - which just wastes both your time and the time of the user trying to help you.

Comment: Please see the image of Brawl Star game it has one thing that affects the user's gameplay is that it shows empty black space on both sides.

Comment: I think its because of restricted area(same area) of map that they want to show to every user. But this creates a problem.I think they have build game in respect of map area.

Comment: @AbhayKumar those black bars ensure each player sees the same area, ensuring that the aspect ratio of the device does not affect gameplay. Otherwise, the aspect ratio of the device could give a competitive advantage in the game. Edit: what is the problem it causes that you are trying to fix? And are you willing to allow the competitive advantage I describe to do that?